# How to add background color to section in shopify liquid

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I am trying to add a background color to my shopify slideshow section but it doesn’t work.

I have tried to add a new div:

```
<div style="background-color:{{block.settings.color_accent}}">
```

But I get broken html error. What am I doing wrong? Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to below code and must have to add this code to you have created block  schema code:

```
{
  "type": "color",
  "id": "color_accent",
  "label": "Buttons color",
  "default": "#FFFFFF"
}
```

And you need to create a div:

```
<div style="background-color:{{block.settings.color_accent}}">
```

Comment: Ok, do you know where to put it? And the closing </div>. I think it will work if I put it on the correct position.

Comment: Yes, after closing the </div> it will work correctly.

Comment: Ok, I have tried but I get errors. Do you know in which line I should put the code?

Comment: If you want to add all block background colors so you need to add this div before LINE No. 161 and then closed the div after closing the section.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. But I can’t get it work. Where should I put the closing tag? I have tried with line 241 but then I get some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'slideshow2.css' style file. I think this external file have a CSS style of  tag which overwrite the style of inline CSS style of div tag.

**Solution 1:**
Try to comment the CSS style of div tag in your 'slideshow2.css' file and check the output on the browser. In this way, you get to know which CSS style overlap or overwrite. And then resolve the specific one.

**Solution 2:**
Use inspect element tool in browser and try to change the color of the div using inline CSS. If it effects the background color, change in to HTML file properly. Otherwise debug the issue and figure out the exact problem why background color is not appearing.

**Solution 3:**
Try to use the background color name directly. Maybe it don't read properly from the desired string `block.settings.color_accent`.

```
<div style="background-color:deepskyblue;"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, do you know where to put it? And the closing </div>. I still get some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to schema

**{
"type": "image_picker",
"id": "background-image",
"label": "Image"
}**

And call it like this on the div

**style="background: url('{{ section. settings.background-image | img_url: 'master' }}')"**

It's the img_url what is giving you trouble, this is the right setting for background.

Comment: I want to add a background color. I think this code will give me an image.